# npm install error darwin

Tags: node.js, macos, terminal, gulp

I tried to run this code from the terminal: "npm install", but i received this error.
how can i fix this?
i tried this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bxvybxYFq2o but seems doesn't works for my issue.
thanks

```html
npm install
npm WARN engineStrict Per-package engineStrict (found in package.json for gulp-concat)
npm WARN engineStrict won't be used in npm 3+. Use the config setting `engine-strict` instead.
npm WARN engineStrict Per-package engineStrict (found in package.json for gulp)
npm WARN engineStrict won't be used in npm 3+. Use the config setting `engine-strict` instead.
npm WARN engineStrict Per-package engineStrict (found in package.json for vinyl-fs)
npm WARN engineStrict won't be used in npm 3+. Use the config setting `engine-strict` instead.
npm ERR! Darwin 12.4.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.0

npm ERR! null == true
```

Answer (score 1):

you should change your package.json. just change "engineStrict" for  "engine-strict" ,and it do work to my project.